# Why is a cursor not closed in on-exit?

Tags: db2-400, rpgle

If i close a cursor in the on-exit section of a procedure the cursor isn't closed properly. If the procedure is used again the cursor can not be opened again. If I close the cursor outside of the on-exit section it is closed properly. Why is this so?

Thanks in advance

```
//---
on-exit fehler;
  if fehler;
    lmap_dispose(positionen);
  endIf;
  exec sql CLOSE fls_position_auflisten;
//---
end-proc;
```

Comment: You don't give the SQLSTATE after the cursor close.  With embedded SQL in RPGLE, the SQLSTATE is the first thing to check whenever anything isn't working as expected.  The second thing to check would be the joblog.  Please add that info.

Comment: Everythings fine I dont have problems with the program flow. I'm just curious. I guess it has something to do with pseudo closed cursors but i don't know exactly.

Comment: what release, are you up to date on PTF's?  Show your on-exit code at least.

Comment: I close SQL cursors within ON-EXIT, and I've never seen an issue.